# how to move data

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, oracle

I have a table with data as following:

```
id  col1  col2
1    c1
1         c2
2    b1
3         a3
4    e1
4         e2
```

Now I need to move this data in another table in such a way that the record that has same id goes as a single record in this new table.

so the new table data would look like this:

```
id     col1    col2
 1       c1      c2
 2       b1
 3               a3
 4       e1      e2
```

now how do we do that?

Comment: Anyone else find it strange that all of the questions mrp asks read like they're directly from a textbook?

Comment: This question does sound worded kind of like a SQL puzzle than a RL scenario, yes.

Comment: Should we downvote him into oblivion? :)

Comment: this should be tagged database, ms-access, postgresql as well ;)

Comment: Are you serious? Can you really insert into a different table in a single select in Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, max(col1) col1, max(col2) col2
into NewTable
from [Table] t 
group by id
```

Comment: Shouldn't you include the `INSERT INTO` or `CREATE TABLE` that goes with this query?  That might make a more complete answer.

Comment: @S.Lott Sure, how about 'into NewTable'?

Comment: That could work. As long as the person can guarantee there is only one record for each id in each column.

Comment: Then what? He will lose some intermediate values, but he said that he needs only one row per `id`, so it's inevitable, right?

Comment: `SELECT INTO` on Oracle is [for populating variables](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_plsql_select_into_clause.htm), not a table.  In SQL Server, the table defined in the INTO can't already exist.  And [MySQL doesn't support the `SELECT INTO` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html).  `INSERT ... SELECT ...` is the most reliable syntax.

Comment: In Oracle I would write `create table tbl as select...`

Answer (score 0):

i don't have a setup to test with, but something like the following should work:

```
select a.id,a.col1,b.col2
into fixed_table
from table1 a
inner join table1 b on a.id = b.id
where a.col1 is not null
and b.col2 is not null;
```

That should create fixed_table from table1.  If you want to move the data back into table1, you could do:

```
drop table1;
select id, col1, col2
from fixed_table
into table1;
```